# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.6

I'm following a practical machine learning tutorial and I am already stuck on the second video.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JcI5Vnw0b2c&t=195s

```
 import pandas as pd
 import Quandl

 df = Quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')
 print(df.head())
```

When I run the same code as the man in the video, all I get is

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

I'm on Windows 10 using Visual Studio 2017 and I already did `pip install pandas`. I have python 3.6.1 installed.

- pip 9.0.1 from C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages (python 3.6).
- pandas (0.19.2).
- Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda 4.3.0 (64-bit)

Comment: make sure that you are running pip and python of the same version. (you might have installed pandas for python 2.7 and using 3.6)

Comment: How do I go about doing that?

Comment: @Dimgold how do I check that I am running pip and python of the same version?

Comment: If you use Anaconda, you should prefer `conda` over `pip` to install packages, when possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had this problem as well and tried a few different things until I realized my python path under settings.json (python.pythonPath) was incorrect and pointing to the wrong directory.  The path should be to where the Python.exe file is under programs.

Answer (score 16):

I had a similar problem which I fixed by doing

```
pip3 install pandas
```

Instead of

```
pip install pandas
```

Answer (score 3):

To make sure that you're using the same `pip` as your `python`, `execute` the `pip` with whole `path` from `python directory` i.e.

```
C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages (python 3.6)\pip install pandas
```

This will install the `pandas` in the same directory

```
Or C:\Python365\pip install pandas

Or C:\Python27\pip install pandas
```

Whichever `Python` you wand to use and `install` the `pandas`

If you want to use a specific version of Python in `Windows cmd`, just add the `path` of that `Python` in `System Variables`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I installed `panda` instead of `pandas`. My installation was missing the last letter `s`.

Answer (score 0):

For python 3.7, type following in CMD:

```
CD C:\Users\[path]\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages
```

then:

```
pip3 install pandas
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was running pandas from an ipython shell. The error message from the original post kept cropping up, despite having `pandas` installed. Then I started reading messages (see below). Installing ipython in the virtual environment didn't help, BUT deactivating the virtual environment and activating it again did.

```
➜ ipython
/.../python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:887: UserWarning: 
Attempting to work in a virtualenv. If you encounter problems, please install 
IPython inside the virtualenv.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Installed pandas was not recognised. Turns out I had two versions of Python. So I deleted one of them and tried installing pandas again. It worked.

Answer (score -2):

I think you can use  conda update pandas  and it should get the most current version for you dist. 
Or,  pip install --update pandas
Also in python 3 quandl will be lowercase. 
Edit.. pandas in on ver. 0.21.0 currently.