# Import pandas is not working in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: Snapshot of Error]

I tried

1. `pip install pandas` on terminal
2. `!pip install pandas` on Jupyter Notebook
3. Creating new environment in anaconda then installing pandas again
4. `conda install pandas` nothing seems to work here

Comment: Have you checked
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44645433/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pandas ?

Comment: also, try restarting the Jupyter kernel following: https://support.labs.cognitiveclass.ai/knowledgebase/articles/857388-how-to-restart-the-jupyter-kernel

Comment: I did I checked 2-3 more but they didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install jupyter
```

then in jupyter notebook:

```
!pip install pandas
```

Comment: Not worked module not found same error again and again

Answer (score 0):

try [installing the ipykernel](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html):

```
conda isntall ipykernel

python -m ipykernel install --user --name myenv --display-name "Python (myenv)"
```