# How do I install modules or pip in python idle

Tags: python, debugging, pip, module

`import pandas` #it works on replit but not on Python IDLE

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/NS/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/module.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas
```

I was trying to use a module named `pandas`.

Comment: Question repeted here [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44645433/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pandas)

Answer (score 1):

Have you downloaded the pandas package first ? Pandas is not pre-installed with Python,

You can use:
**pip install pandas**
in your python console to download it

Also make sure you are installing pandas on the same Pyhthon version your IDE use